# Running manage.py shell with -c flag within docker-compose run

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a script that runs Django code in my docker container.

My initial plan was to run the following:

```
    docker-compose run web python manage.py shell -c "import django; print(django.__version__)"
```

However, that isn't working: it prompts `manage.py shell: error: unrecognized arguments: django; print(django.__version__)` (It leaves out the `import`, if you pay close attention). I guess it has to do with the fact that -c is a flag shared both by manage.py and by `bash`, or at least that's what I gathered from [the docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) and [Django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-shell-command).

If I run `docker-compose run web bash`, it prompts the shell, where I can do `python manage.py shell -c "..."`.

How can I do that in just one step?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried on my setup - runs without any issues and gives me version of my project

Comment: shell -c "python manage.py -c 'import django; print(django.__version__)'"

Comment: None of this worked, I'm afraid. I have updated the question with more information if that aids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```sh
docker exec -it <container_name> sh -c echo "import django;
print(django._ _version_ _)" | python manage.py shell
```